# C NDK ndk-build not recognizing headers error: undefined reference to 'cpBBTreeNew'

Tags: c, android-ndk, chipmunk

I am relatively new to C

I am working to port Chipmunk physics engine into my project, however, when I try to run ndk-build I get the following...

> /Users/user/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/chipmunk_shared/src/cpSpace.o: in function cpSpaceInit:jni/src/cpSpace.c:103: error: undefined reference to 'cpBBTreeNew'
>   /Users/user/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/chipmunk_shared/src/cpSpace.o: in function cpSpaceInit:jni/src/cpSpace.c:104: error: undefined reference to 'cpBBTreeNew'
>   /Users/user/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/chipmunk_shared/src/cpSpace.o: in function cpSpaceInit:jni/src/cpSpace.c:105: error: undefined reference to 'cpBBTreeSetVelocityFunc'

When I grep for that class I see...

> ~/Documents/workspace/Chipmunk$ grep -r cpBBTreeNew jni/
>   jni//include/chipmunk/cpSpatialIndex.h:cpSpatialIndex* cpBBTreeNew(cpSpatialIndexBBFunc bbfunc, cpSpatialIndex *staticIndex);
>   jni//src/cpBBTree.c:cpBBTreeNew(cpSpatialIndexBBFunc bbfunc, cpSpatialIndex *staticIndex)
>   jni//src/cpSpace.c: space->staticShapes = cpBBTreeNew((cpSpatialIndexBBFunc)cpShapeGetBB, NULL);
>   jni//src/cpSpace.c: space->activeShapes = cpBBTreeNew((cpSpatialIndexBBFunc)cpShapeGetBB, space->staticShapes);

So I know the .h file is there and I confirmed it was getting loaded through another .h class. I don't think this is the issue but here is my Android.mk...

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := chipmunk_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libchipmunk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
src/chipmunk.c \
....
src/cpVect.c

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/chipmunk

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/chipmunk
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c99

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

########### Static library

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := chipmunk_static

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libchipmunk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
src/chipmunk.c \
....
src/cpVect.c

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/chipmunk

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/chipmunk
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c99

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like cpBBTree.o is missing when linking. Is cpBBTree.c missing from LOCAL_SRC_FILES?

Comment: Good call I kinda stole the Android.mk and whoever made it last time didn't have it. Thanks!

Comment: Probably better to open another question